# Issue with drawing png file into swing GUI

Tags: java, swing

I am facing an issue that I am not able to draw an png image into my swing GUI into `JPanel` (which I am adding into `JScrollPane` after).

Here is my code I am trying to use for this.

```
if(processCreated == true){
     System.out.println("updating tree of organisms");
     processCreated = false; 
     updateTree();
     try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Svet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
     tree = new File(path+"/out.png"); //File
     try {
        treeImage = ImageIO.read(tree); //BufferedImage
        tp = new TreePane(treeImage.getScaledInstance( 500, 500 ,treeImage.SCALE_SMOOTH)); // my class, implementation below
        treeOutput.add(tp); //adding "JPanel" with picture into GUI
        treeOutput.repaint();
     } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Svet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
}
```

After this the `JScrollPane` remains empty. Is there anything wrong with my code? You can find what is what in comments.

Here is my `TreePane` class

```
public class TreePane extends JPanel{
   Image img;

   public TreePane( Image img ){
      this.img = img;
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
      super.paintComponent(g);
      int imgX = 0;
      int imgY = 0;

      g.drawImage(img, imgX, imgY, this);
   }
}
```

Comment: The preferred size of `TreePane` is (0, 0), and that's what the scroll pane uses. You could override `getPreferredSize()`, but the simplest would be just using `JLabel` for displaying the image.

Comment: I agree with @kiheru: don't make things difficult -- use a JLabel, put it into the JScrollPane, and simply set its Icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely your TreePane is layed out to size 0,0 and therefore you'll never see anything. Try adding a breakpoint and inspecting in paintComponent - it might not even ever get called.

To fix, you should explicitly set the size of your TreePane before adding it to the JScrollPane.

```
    tp = new TreePane(treeImage.getScaledInstance( 500, 500 ,treeImage.SCALE_SMOOTH)); // my class, implementation below
    tp.setSize(myWidth, myHeight);
    treeOutput.add(tp); //adding "JPanel" with picture into GUI
    treeOutput.repaint();
```

Comment: Rather than setting size, something most layout managers don't respect, why not have it override `getPreferredSize`, and base the return value on the size of the image?

Comment: Actually probably easier is to simply put a JLabel into the JScrollPane and set its Icon.

Comment: This was helpfull as well. But in my own solution the issue was with using Swing component but with AWT component it works fine. Thanks all for your help.